# Django: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'serialize'

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-serializer

**models.py**

```
class UpdateQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def serialize(self):
        qs = self
        return serialize('json', qs, fields=('user', 'content', 'image'))

class UpdateManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return UpdateQuerySet(self.model, using=self._db)
class Tools_booked(models.Model):
    auto_increment_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user=models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    component = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    booked = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,blank=True)

    objects = UpdateManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.component

    def serialize(self):
        return serialize("json", [self], fields=['auto_increment_id','user','component','booked'])
```

in **views.py**

```
from django.core.serializers import serialize
class SerializedDetialView(View):
     def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        obj = Tools_booked.objects.get(auto_increment_id=1)
        json_data = obj.serialize()
        return HttpResponse(json_data, content_type='application/json')


class SerializedListView(View):
     def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        qs = Tools_booked.objects.all()
        json_data = qs.serialize()
        return HttpResponse(json_data, content_type='application/json')
```

I have seen the similar question, it is solved with a new class view. But why this code is not working. The error it showing for SerializedListView and SerializedDetialView urls is

```
'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'serialize'
```

and

```
'Tools_booked' object has no attribute 'serialize'
```

Why this error exist and how can we solve this error without creating a new class.

**edit**

> ```
> in views.py, line 84, in get
>     json_data = qs.serialize()
>     AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'serialize'
> ```

Comment: Please edit the question with complete traceback of your error.

Comment: @ans2human added traceback

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/serialization/#serializing-data

```
from django.core import serializers

obj_list= Tools_booked.objects.filter(auto_increment_id=1)
json_data = serializers.serialize("json", obj_list )
return HttpResponse(json_data, content_type='application/json')
```